# Is it possible to extend group isomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

First note that I am naive to this research area.

Let $G$ be a finite group and so is $H$. Let $K$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $K'$ be a subgroup of $H$ and both subgroups are non-trivial. I know a map $\phi$ which is an isomorphism from $K$ to $K'$,

**Question :** Is it possible to extend this map $\phi$ from $G$ to $H$ ( assuming  $G \cong H$)? if yes how?

Please feel free to share wiki-article or any thing on it, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not always possible.

For an example, take the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$. This group has a center of order $2$, and also a non-central element of order $2$. There is of course an isomorphism between the center and the subgroup generated by this element, but this cannot extend to an isomorphism from the group to itself, since such an isomorphism would preserve the center.

Comment: It's not even possible for abelian groups. The abelian $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ will also work, since it has one non-trivial square.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, that is a great example. In both cases one finds two subgroups that are isomorphic but different, and where one is characteristic.

Comment: At the opposite end, I think that the simple $\textrm{GL}(4,2)$ gives a counterexample too: it has two sorts of involution which can't be interchanged by an automorphism.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft You have answered my original question,  but is it possible that if I put more condition on subgroups then it may be possible.

Comment: @ddddd Well, sometimes it is possible and sometimes it is not. Whether there is some sort of nice condition that ensures it is always possible I don't know.

Comment: @ Tobias Kildetoft If two underlying groups on which isomorphism is known comes from center then it seems possible to me.

Comment: @ddddd I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: @ddddd, my abelian example shows that's not so.